# Plumbers putty removal

Tags: putty

We had a granite top and a black stone sink installed in our kitchenette.  I installed the black strainer and disposal rings.  I used non-staining plumbers putty under the rings.  The putty that squeezed out around the strainers is a light color and is very noticeable.  After I removed the excess putty around each strainer a small amount remained in the groove around the outside edge of each strainer.  How can I remove the small amount down in the grooves?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't already have one, go buy a box of wooden toothpicks or bamboo skewers. Very handy for getting into little crevices like that.

Comment: Excellent idea but don't be surprised if more comes out as it settles. Try to ignore it, normal use should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the groove between the strainer and sink, you might be able to make that look better by tightening the strainer a little more—slow and steady pressure with good dose of patience is needed:  as the gap closes, it becomes harder for the putty to squeeze out.

Then just wipe off the excess and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly use a butter knife for this, need one that is a bit thin.  Since you are in the kitchen already should be easy.